# Search users with the API filtering case insesitive with substringof

Tags: core-api

I'm currently using the API to search for users like this:

```
/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Id,Title&$filter=substringof('string', Title)
```

However, I have the problem that in this case, the substringof filter is case sensitive. So, when a usear searches for say "Charles" he gets all the Charles, but when he searches for "charles" he gets nothing.

Is there a way to do this, while at the same time making the filter case insesitive?

I guess I could do it like this:

```
/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Id,Title&$filter=substringof('string', Title) or substringof('String', Title)
```

And do two filters, one for string without capitalization and one with it.

But surely a better soulution would be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tolower` or `toupper`

```
/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Id,Title&$filter=substringof(tolower('string'), tolower(Title))
```